# Is encodeRestorableState() supported in NSWindowController?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nswindowcontroller

For the life of me, I can't figure it out. I think I tried everything to have the `encodeRestorableState(with:)` method get called in my `NSWindowController` subclass but it just doesn't.

After spending a few hours on this, I'm thinking it might not actually be supported at all. What does [this piece of documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) mean then?

[image]

Note that it says to **use** the method instead of overriding/implementing it. Maybe that's where I got it wrong.

---

### Update

Digging further, I found out that the window I create in my `NSWindowController` subclass has its `windowController` property set to `nil`. I guess that's the reason the window doesn't tell the controller to encode its state. I'm now figuring out why it's `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Basically, that's how I was creating the window controller in `AppDelegate`:

```
MainWindowController().showWindow(self)
```

I didn't retain any references to the window controller instance, and since `NSWindow`'s `windowController` property is `weak`, the window controller was being deallocated. And that's what caused many issues, including the one in this question. I hit other problems because of this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `invalidateRestorableState()` for your NSViewController/NSWindowController subclass. At a later point the `encodeRestorableState(with:)` will get called.